# what is the way to declare function like php array_count_values in c#?

Tags: c#, arrays, count

i want to declare function in c# that accept an array an 
return the Counts all the values of this array

like [array_count_values](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php) in php

```
$array = array(1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 5 );

return 

Array
(
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 1
    [3] => 2
    [5] => 1
)
```

what is the efficient  way to do this ?

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
int[] array = new[] { 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 5 };
var counts = array.GroupBy(x => x)
                  .Select(g => new { Value = g.Key, Count = g.Count() });
foreach(var count in counts) {
    Console.WriteLine("[{0}] => {1}", count.Value, count.Count);
}
```

Alternatively, you can get a `Dictionary<int, int>` like so:

```
int[] array = new[] { 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 5 };
var counts = array.GroupBy(x => x)
                  .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Count());
```

Comment: It's not a single-function answer -- that doesn't exist -- but it's better than the loop I was preparing. +1

Comment: thanks , how can i found the max count.count in this array results ?

Comment: var maxValue = counts.Max(g => g.Value);

Answer (score 2):

**Edit**

Sorry, I see now that my previous answer was not correct.  You are wanting to count each type of unique value.

You can use a Dictionary to store the value types:

```
object[] myArray = { 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 5 };
Dictionary<object, int> valueCount = new Dictionary<object, int>();
foreach (object obj in myArray)
{
    if (valueCount.ContainsKey(obj))
        valueCount[obj]++;
    else
        valueCount[obj] = 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be able to count something besides ints try this

```
public static Dictionary<dynamic, int> Count(dynamic[] array) 
  {

   Dictionary<dynamic, int> counts = new Dictionary<dynamic, int>();

   foreach(var item in array) {

    if (!counts.ContainsKey(item)) {
     counts.Add(item, 1);
    } else {
     counts[item]++;
    }


   }

  return counts;    
  }
```